# Unable to install @ionic-enterprise/couchbase-lite

Tags: angular, ionic4, capacitor

When I use `ionic4` + `capacitor` for work, I try to use npm install `@ionic-enterprise/couchbase-lite`, it has been unable to install succeed(*I have successfully registered my enterprise key and include this plugin*). As shown below
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dn5p.png)

Comment: Are there any errors found during install?

Comment: There is a deleted answer about updating npm fixing the problem. What version of npm were you using and what version are you using now?